# FSR using Python

Tags: python

So I don't really know much about programming and I need help for my senior research project in physics. I have a Force Sensing Resistor (Interlink Electronics 1.5" Square) that I'm using programming provided by phidgets.com (the programming I found is attached below). My issue is that my sensor is only taking measurements when there is a recognized stimulus and I want it to take measurements continually. How can I change the programming to make it take measurements continually?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Copyright 2010 Phidgets Inc.
This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 Canada License. 
To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/ca/
"""

__author__ = 'Adam Stelmack'
__version__ = '2.1.8'
__date__ = 'May 17 2010'

#Basic imports
from ctypes import *
import sys
import random
#Phidget specific imports
from Phidgets.PhidgetException import PhidgetErrorCodes, PhidgetException
from Phidgets.Events.Events import AttachEventArgs, DetachEventArgs, ErrorEventArgs, InputChangeEventArgs, OutputChangeEventArgs, SensorChangeEventArgs
from Phidgets.Devices.InterfaceKit import InterfaceKit

#Create an interfacekit object
try:
    interfaceKit = InterfaceKit()
except RuntimeError as e:
    print("Runtime Exception: %s" % e.details)
    print("Exiting....")
    exit(1)

#Information Display Function
def displayDeviceInfo():
    print("|------------|----------------------------------|--------------|------------|")
    print("|- Attached -|-              Type              -|- Serial No. -|-  Version -|")
    print("|------------|----------------------------------|--------------|------------|")
    print("|- %8s -|- %30s -|- %10d -|- %8d -|" % (interfaceKit.isAttached(), interfaceKit.getDeviceName(), interfaceKit.getSerialNum(), interfaceKit.getDeviceVersion()))
    print("|------------|----------------------------------|--------------|------------|")
    print("Number of Digital Inputs: %i" % (interfaceKit.getInputCount()))
    print("Number of Digital Outputs: %i" % (interfaceKit.getOutputCount()))
    print("Number of Sensor Inputs: %i" % (interfaceKit.getSensorCount()))

#Event Handler Callback Functions
def interfaceKitAttached(e):
    attached = e.device
    print("InterfaceKit %i Attached!" % (attached.getSerialNum()))

def interfaceKitDetached(e):
    detached = e.device
    print("InterfaceKit %i Detached!" % (detached.getSerialNum()))

def interfaceKitError(e):
    try:
        source = e.device
        print("InterfaceKit %i: Phidget Error %i: %s" % (source.getSerialNum(), e.eCode, e.description))
    except PhidgetException as e:
        print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))

def interfaceKitInputChanged(e):
    source = e.device
    print("InterfaceKit %i: Input %i: %s" % (source.getSerialNum(), e.index, e.state))

def interfaceKitSensorChanged(e):
    source = e.device
    print("InterfaceKit %i: Sensor %i: %i" % (source.getSerialNum(), e.index, e.value))

def interfaceKitOutputChanged(e):
    source = e.device
    print("InterfaceKit %i: Output %i: %s" % (source.getSerialNum(), e.index, e.state))

#Main Program Code
try:
    interfaceKit.setOnAttachHandler(interfaceKitAttached)
    interfaceKit.setOnDetachHandler(interfaceKitDetached)
    interfaceKit.setOnErrorhandler(interfaceKitError)
    interfaceKit.setOnInputChangeHandler(interfaceKitInputChanged)
    interfaceKit.setOnOutputChangeHandler(interfaceKitOutputChanged)
    interfaceKit.setOnSensorChangeHandler(interfaceKitSensorChanged)
except PhidgetException as e:
    print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))
    print("Exiting....")
    exit(1)

print("Opening phidget object....")

try:
    interfaceKit.openPhidget()
except PhidgetException as e:
    print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))
    print("Exiting....")
    exit(1)

print("Waiting for attach....")

try:
    interfaceKit.waitForAttach(10000)
except PhidgetException as e:
    print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))
    try:
        interfaceKit.closePhidget()
    except PhidgetException as e:
        print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))
        print("Exiting....")
        exit(1)
    print("Exiting....")
    exit(1)
else:
    displayDeviceInfo()

print("Setting the data rate for each sensor index to 4ms....")
for i in range(interfaceKit.getSensorCount()):
    try:

        interfaceKit.setDataRate(i, 4)
    except PhidgetException as e:
        print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))

print("Press Enter to quit....")

chr = sys.stdin.read(1)

print("Closing...")

try:
    interfaceKit.closePhidget()
except PhidgetException as e:
    print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))
    print("Exiting....")
    exit(1)

print("Done.")
exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the following line:

```
 for i in range(interfaceKit.getSensorCount()):
```

, this will have to be changed to either an infinite loop (until shutdown) or something else. The thing is, it is very open ended on what you put in the range of the for loop. I would look at examples online of for-loops and sensors so nothing breaks.

You may want to look into the concept of polling, and also look into the module `timeit`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Unix machine you can set a cron job to run a simple logic program. You'd remove all the event handlers and just connect to the Phidget device, then get the reading from your sensor using: value = interfaceKit.getSensorValue(sensorindex), you'd then need to write value to a file.

If you want to have the program running from a terminal or something you could again remove the event handlers and just put a loop into the code after you've attached the Phidget.

```
print("Press Ctrl-C to quit....")

try:
    while True:
        try:
            value = interfaceKit.getSensorValue(0) # index of your sensor
            print("%i" % (value))
        except PhidgetException as e:
            print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))

        time.sleep(5) # in seconds

except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print("Closing...")
    pass
```

This will get a reading every 5 seconds until someone presses ctrl-c.

Good luck!